# Как осуществить перебор пар в списке Python

Tags: python, list, перебор

Есть список `d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. Нужно перебрать все пары для выполнения каких-либо действий с ними, например:

```
a = 1
b = 2
a+b
```

```
a = 1
b = 3
a+b
```

```
a = 1
b = 4
a+b
```

Далее 15,16,21,23,24,25,26,31,32,34,35,36...

Список будет большой - примерно 1млн чисел

Comment: Два вложенных цикла for попробуйте применить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import itertools

d = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
for a, b in itertools.combinations(d, 2):
    print(a, b)
```

И дальше делаете с a, b что хотите.

Comment: Спасибо большое <3

Comment: @nummary  чуть упростил